# How to load more data when I click the button in android using firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two set of data store in firestore (quality, fairness). They both are the reviews from the users, and I want to make a list of comments sorted by its date to show both quality and fairness reviews at the same time. It works fine, but I want to work further to create a "see more" button. When the users enter the reviews page, it will show only two comments each time unless the users press "see more" button. The program will put another two comments into the List and shown in the UI. The picture is the structure of my firebase firestore database
[image]

> The path is like: "user_review" |- "(usr_id)" |- "quality" |-
>   "(comment_person_uid)" 
>   |-post_id/quality_rating/review_time/reviewer_id/text_review

[image]

Here is the function I have to load very first two reviews, the otherProfileID is the (usr_id). It works fine as I set the limit(2)

```
has_comm = new ArrayList<>();
        quality_cr = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user_reviews").document(otherProfileID).collection("quality").orderBy("review_time").limit(2); //.whereGreaterThan("text_review", "")
        //final Query fairness_cr = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user_reviews").document(otherProfileID).collection("fairness").whereGreaterThan("text_review", "");
        quality_cr.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d ("two_only", "print");
                    has_comm.clear();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                        String quality_rating = doc.get("quality_rating").toString();
                        String post_id = doc.get("post_id").toString();
                        String review_time = doc.get("review_time").toString();
                        String reviewer_id = doc.get("reviewer_id").toString();
                        String text_review = doc.get("text_review").toString();
                        single_review = new Review(quality_rating, post_id, review_time, reviewer_id, text_review);
                        has_comm.add(single_review);
                        review_adapter = new Review_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), has_comm);
                        Log.d ("two_only", has_comm + " ");
                        rvr.setAdapter(review_adapter);
                        //rvr.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the button when I click the ***Button*** see more, I used startAfter(quality_cr) as the above query but it gives me run time error

```
see_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //This query gives me run-time error
                Query two_more = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user_reviews").document(otherProfileID).collection("quality").orderBy("review_time").startAfter(quality_cr).limit(2); //.orderBy("review_time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                two_more.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            has_comm.clear();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                                String quality_rating = doc.get("quality_rating").toString();
                                String post_id = doc.get("post_id").toString();
                                String review_time = doc.get("review_time").toString();
                                String reviewer_id = doc.get("reviewer_id").toString();
                                String text_review = doc.get("text_review").toString();
                                single_review = new Review(quality_rating, post_id, review_time, reviewer_id, text_review);
                                has_comm.add(single_review);
                                review_adapter = new Review_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), has_comm);
                                rvr.setAdapter(review_adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                Log.d("two_only", quality_rating + " " + post_id + " " + has_comm);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

and this is my recyclerview and review model for you reference only.

Review_Adapter

```
public class Review_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Review_Adapter.CommentViewHolder>{
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String commented_userid = "";
    public ArrayList<Review> comm_list;
    private HashMap<String, String> review_hash;

    public Review_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Review> comm_list) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.comm_list = comm_list;
    }

    @Override
    public CommentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_comment, parent, false);
        return new CommentViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CommentViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Review c = comm_list.get(position);
        holder.Comment.setText(c.getText_review());

        String oldstring = c.getReview_time();
        Date dt = new Date(oldstring);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").format(dt);
        holder.CommentedDate.setText(timeStamp);

        commented_userid = c.getReviewer_id();
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(commented_userid).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        Map udata = task.getResult().getData();
                        String first_name = udata.get("first_name").toString();
                        String last_name = udata.get("last_name").toString();
                        String fullname = first_name + " " + last_name;
                        holder.CommentedFullName.setText(fullname);

                        String username = udata.get("username").toString();
                        holder.CommentedUser.setText(username);
                        if(udata.get("profile_pic")!=null){
                            Map pic = (Map) udata.get("profile_pic");
                            String url = pic.get("url_link").toString();
                            Log.d("review_adaper",url);
                            Picasso.get().load(url).into(holder.CommentedIcon);
                        }
                    }
                });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return comm_list.size();
    }


    public class CommentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView CommentedIcon;
        private TextView CommentedFullName;
        private TextView CommentedUser;
        private TextView CommentedDate;
        private TextView Comment;

        public CommentViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            CommentedIcon= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.commented_icon);
            CommentedFullName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commented_fullname);
            CommentedUser = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commented_user);
            CommentedDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commented_date);
            Comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commented);
        }
    }

    private void removeItem(int value) {
        comm_list.remove(value);
        notifyItemRemoved(value);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(value, comm_list.size());
    }
```

```
public class Review {
    String quality_rating;
    String post_id;
    String review_time;
    String reviewer_id;
    String text_review;


    public Review(){
        //
    }

    public Review(String quality_rating, String post_id, String review_time, String reviewer_id, String text_review){
        this.quality_rating=quality_rating;
        this.post_id=post_id;
        this.review_time=review_time;
        this.reviewer_id=reviewer_id;
        this.text_review=text_review;

    }

    public String getQuality_rating() {
        return quality_rating;
    }

    public String getPost_id() {
        return post_id;
    }

    public String getReview_time() {
        return review_time;
    }

    public String getReviewer_id() {
        return reviewer_id;
    }

    public String getText_review() {
        return text_review;
    }
```

However, it does not show the two new data when I press the button. Any help would appreciate. I want to load first two reviews in the UI first, and when I press the see_more button, it shows two more reviewed comments until the end.

Answer (score 0):

The quality_cr is a query. But you need to pass the documentSnapshot or the fields you use in orderby for for startAfter. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#startAfter(java.lang.Object...)

So in your OnCompleteListener you have to store either your field or the documentSnapshot and then use them in the startAfter on button click

I hope you got it.